# Responsive image

Tags: html, image, srcset

I'm trying to get responsive images to work for my header image.

```
<img srcset="/media/1501/here_header.jpg 960w, /media/1650/here_small.jpg 320w" sizes="(width: 960px)">
```

This is what I have so far, and it kind of works but when it gets larger than 960px the image keep getting larger, I want it to stop when it reaches 960px.

```
<img srcset="/media/1501/here_header.jpg 960w, /media/1650/here_small.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 960px) 100vw">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can and should control the displayed width with CSS (i.e.: `max-width: 960;`), but you also should inform the browser the displayed size via the `sizes` attribute. The default of the sizes attribute is 100vw:

`sizes="(max-width: 960px) 100vw"` is transfered to `sizes="(max-width: 960px) 100vw, 100vw"`, which basically means, if the viewport is lower 960px use the full viewport, otherwise use the full viewport, which doesn't make much sense. What you want is the following:

`sizes="(max-width: 960px) 100vw, 960px"`

You can also write:
`sizes="(min-width: 960px) 960px, 100vw"` or as shorthand: `sizes="(min-width: 960px) 960px"`

```
<img srcset="/media/1501/here_header.jpg 960w, /media/1650/here_small.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 960px) 100vw, 960px" style="max-width:960px;">
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Could you mark this as the answer?